# How to unify behavior of infowindow scrolling in chrome/firefox/IE

Tags: javascript, css, google-maps, google-chrome, firefox

I'm using google maps api in my application. I found out different behaviour of scrolling in infowindow. In google chrome when there is an infobox opened with overflowing text, I can scroll it with the mousewheel. If I do the same thing with firefox or IE it starts to zoom in / out. I made a short comparision video to understand my problem better. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-MUerJFebOc

I like the 'greedy' gestureHandling, where I can use the mousewheel to zoom in desired situations. I don't want to use 'cooperative' gestureHandling, which somehow solves my problem. Do someone knows a solution/workaround for that? Thank you!

Comment: It could be nice to post here a sample code to reproduce the issue. Have a look at [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I made an example script here: http://jsfiddle.net/p7me382k/1/

Comment: The problem was resolved by google.